# jQuery Galleria sizing issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, galleria

I'm trying to simplify galleria to remove most of the elements and styling around it within the classic theme.  I really just want my image to scale to the galleria container, not the galleria stage.  How does one control the relationship between the stage and the container?  I also tried to remove the thumbnails by useing the 'thumbnails' option and the theme API by removing the 'thumbnails-container' element from the DOM, but no dice.

I'm trying to figure this out to create a really simple layout that maximizes the scaled image with the padding around it and at the bottom, where the thumbnails would be.

Any help on this would be great, I'm still re-reading the galleria docs as well.  I'm open to simpler plugins as well but the scaling, centering, and lightbox are key.

Thanks!

```
if ($("#gallery").children().size() > 0) {
    Galleria.loadTheme("../../Content/themes/galleria/galleria.classic.js");
    Galleria.run("#gallery");
    Galleria.configure({
        lightbox: true,
        dummy: 'http://c400976.r76.cf1.rackcdn.com/no_label_graphic.png',
        width: 325,
        height: 325,
        thumbnails: false,
        layerFollow: false

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to alternatives, I'd suggest [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox). Does not have the thumbnails like Galleria, but the rest should fit your needs. Easy to work with. Galleria can be tedious to modify.

Comment: That's cool, but I need the slideshow on the page, not in a lightbox like colorbox.

Comment: I think it has that option too, didn't you say " lightbox are key" ??

Comment: yeah, for each image in the slideshow I want the lighbox option, like galleria...  I'll check it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to add some CSS:

```
body .galleria-stage{top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0}
```

This will make the stage fill up the container. Then just set `thumbnails:false` to prevent the creation of thumbnails.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZaG2X/